# Scroll to the end after Jquery form is submited

Tags: jquery

I have a chat based on jQuery Form Plugin. Below is the script allowing me to scroll down to the latest message when page is open, refresh chat body to see new new messages, and handle input field (id=11) while sending message.

I want to scroll down to the latest message once message is sent and chat body is reloaded. I tried to this in 'success' function of #myForm but it doesn't work.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('scroll').scrollTop = 9999999999;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  refreshChat();

});

function refreshChat() {

  $('#scroll').load('getchat.php', function() {
    setTimeout(refreshChat, 1000);
  });
}


var options = {
  clearForm: true,
  resetForm: true,
  beforeSubmit: function() {
    $('#11').val('sending...');
    $('#11').attr('disabled', true);
  },
  success: function() {
    $('#11').val('');
    $('#11').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#scroll').scrollTop(9999999999); // Part I'm trying to work on
  }

};

$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="message" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="sendmessage.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="large-11 medium-10 small-9 columns">
          <input type="text" name="message" id="11" class="chat-message radius" placeholder="Type your message here...">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 medium-2 small-3 columns">
          <input type="submit" class="button postfix radius" value="Send">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how about $('html, body').scrollTop($(document).height());

Comment: I still need to scroll chat history... will not brake this? Could you tell me more where and how to add this line?

Comment: how about something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/oyb3r6u8/3/

Comment: testing it on page provided and it doesn't scroll to the last message once it sent

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a function like in this jquery bot 
https://github.com/syaifulsz/simple-jquery-chatbot

here's the function called after each message

```
function scrollToMessage() {
    var msgBox = $('#the name of the box');
    var height = msgBox[0].scrollHeight;
    msgBox.scrollTop(height);
}
```